# jQuery .stopPropagation() Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My click function works with .stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation() if the click event is triggerd the page reload. How can I stop / remove this ?

```
 $('#test').on('click', function(e) {       
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: thanks thats works :) could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
$('#test').on('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
});
```